# Selenium SessionNotCreatedException Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

the code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://google.com/')
```

the error returned is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Joshua/Desktop/coding/PYTHON/kahoot/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

i am using:

1. python 3.6
2. selenium (up to date as of posting this)
3. geckodriver 0.26
4. visual studio code
5. windows 10

thanks for your time

Comment: it's usually compatibility issues please make sure you're following this chart for your installations [Compatibility Selenium / Geckodriver / Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html)

Comment: Please share the entire error message.